# Specification Pattern Modified (Candidate In Constructor)

Tags: design-patterns, specification-pattern

I know that design patterns are set by the design and not by specific code yet sometimes I get concerned that I bent the pattern too much and no longer follow the design.

For Example Specification Pattern looks like this:

```
 public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate);
}
```

But to me this isn't very readable:

```
 _customerAccountIsActive
.And(_hasReachedRentalThreshold)
.And(_customerAccountHasLateFees)
.IsSatisfiedBy(this);
```

So I changed it to pass the candidate inside the constructor:

```
public abstract class Specification<TEntity> : ISpecification<TEntity>
{
    protected TEntity _candidate;

    public Specification(TEntity candidate)
    {
        _candidate = candidate;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfied()
    {
        return IsSatisfiedBy(_candidate);
    }
}
```

And I even Overloaded The bool operator so I can write something like this:

```
_customerAccountIsActive 
&& _customerAccountHasLateFees
&& _hasReachedRentalThreshold
```

Now I'd like to know from someone more experienced with design patterns whether I'm twisting this too much and what are the risks I should be aware of.

Comment: I have same question, anybody with experiences comes?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the similar question here [How to adapt the Specification pattern to evaluate a combination of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327511/how-to-adapt-the-specification-pattern-to-evaluate-a-combination-of-objects). I have same issue with you and there is 2 adaptation I can think.

My problem is comparing 2 object of 2 different type of TEntity in one specification.

Right now, I'm trying to add the second entity to the IsSatisfied(T candidate) like this:
IsSatisfied(T firstCandidate, K secondCandidate)

So the Specification will be come Specification, but I think I will lose the ​ability of combine the Specification with Specification.

So far, I haven't had any good idea about adding second candidate into specification.

There is 2 workarounds that I can think:

1. Using a parameter object and use this object as an candidate object:

   ```
   public class ParameterObject<T,K>
   {
     public T FirstObject { get; set; }
     public K SecondObject { get; set; {
   }


   public SomeSpecification: Specification<ParameterObject<Order, Customer>>

   public bool IsSatisfied(ParameterObject candidate)
   {
      // do some check between order and customer candidates.
   }
   ```
2. Using contructor injection:

   ```
   public class OutOfRangeOrderSpeficiation: Specification<Order>
   {
      private ICriteria _criteria;

       public OutOfRangeOrderSpeficiation(ICriteria criteria)
       {
          _criteria = criteria;
       }

       public bool IsSatisfied(Order candidate)
       {
         // comparing between order candidate and _criteria.
         return false;
       }
   }
   ```